# Omni Channel Tab Focus

Tags: omnichannel

We have implemented Omni Channel with auto accept on cases and its working. The issue is that when you are working on a case in the console and omni channel pops a case then the browser focus is switched to the new case, which is annoying our service agents. I see no way to control this behaviour but wanted to ask if anyone has had similar issue and found a work around or solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Lightning. This is a "Classic-only" issue/feature, and I don't think there is a simple/configuration workaround.

To recap:
**- Classic Console w/ Omni-Channel:** if your Presence Configuration is set to "Automatically Accept Requests" you will be automatically redirected to the new request even if you have a record open and are in the middle of something.
**- Lightning Console w/ Omni-Channel:** if your Presence Configuration is set to "Automatically Accept Requests" you will NOT automatically redirect to the newly accepted request. The newly accepted record will simply be added to your view in a new tab on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Krigi I'm using LEX and Present = Auto-Accept. When getting new work it's auto-focussing.

I'm using a custom object and yeah - it keeps opening the next tab. Stops agents focussing on a certain type of work item.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/183547)